# What is dd if=/dev/zero of=/EMPTY bs=1M

Tags: linux, filesystems, vagrant

Often times I see this command for use when creating a Vagrant box

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/EMPTY bs=1M
```

To me it seams that it is copying a lot of NULL characters into a file named EMPTY at the FS root 1MB at a time. My question is how does doing this optimize the space usage on the disk once the file is removed.

Comment: this is sparse file http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It effectively writes zeroes to all empty space on the volume; this allows for better compression of the physical file containing the virtual disk.

Comment: I've used this "technique" a lot. I'd install Windows for my family on a partition, filled the filesystem with zeroes like this, and then simply gzipped the entire partition. The restore was extremely simple, and the backed up file was very compact. :)